# How to parse data from MySQL table into another table using Mysql script

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table : **Country (id int, name varchar(100), sports varchar(300))**

```
------------------------------------
id   |  name  |  Sports
------------------------------------
1    | USA    | {Football}{Basket}
2    | Canada | {Swimming}
..   | ...    | ...
------------------------------------
```

In order to normalize the country table, I need an **MySQL** script to loop through each row in country table and then extract the sport into a new table **Sport (id, sportName).** like this:

```
---------------------------------
id  |  sport
---------------------------------
1          | Football
2          | Basket
3          | Swimming
..         | .....
-----------------------------------
```

and ***Finally*** I need to create a table **Country_Sports** to save each country like :
 Country_Sports  ( country_id, sport_id).**

```
-----------------------------
country_id   | sport_id
-----------------------------
1            | 2
1            | 3
3            | 1 
-------------------------
```

I created a function to separate the "{"  "}" , but still not enough because I don't know how to use it to extract all sports for each country.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
delim, '');
```

example :

```
 SPLIT_STR(Sports, '{', 2)
```

Comment: Where is your trial? This could be done directly with mysql or with the help of php.

Comment: I need mySQL only without php! see update please

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created table country, now you can create table sports from table
country with the same
columns as follows

```
create table sport as select * from country;
select * from sport;
```

This simply means that all the columns and rows in the country table will be used
to create sports table.

An addition:

Your question is somehow confusing. If you are talking about querying the records seperately, you can 
use the id or country name

For instance to query sports column for USA as country, it becomes

```
select name from country where id=1;   or

select * from country where name='USA';
```

consequently, to  query sports column for Canada as country, it becomes

```
select name from country where id=2;   or

select * from country where name='Canada';
```

If this is not what you want, can you please organize your question so that we can understand you.

Comment: what is the script to extract "{"  "}"  for each country it is like loop, before table creation.

Comment: it will extract all the content of the country table and create a table sport with it

Comment: I know that, but how to separate all sports inside the column: sports, please look at my country table

Comment: any answer plz.

Comment: I have updated the answer given to you. please check the answer above to see if it solve your problem

Comment: it is not what I need, any way tx